# why .destroy() doesn't completly free the memory used by a tkinter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

This should always keep the same space in the RAM but it doesn't? Why ? tkinter documentation say that it is the method to use if you want to free space.

```
from tkinter import Tk,Frame,Entry

app = Tk()
frame = Frame(app)
while True:
    e = Entry(frame)
    e.destroy()
```

I tried del, it is worse.
Just launch the script and look at your task manager.

Comment: why do you think it should use the same space in RAM ? System may use complex system to manage memory and it doesn't have to gives you the same memory. And Python doesn't have to remove objects at once but it has Garbage Collector for this and it may free space in differen way that you expect.

Comment: I tested it on LInux and nothing changed. Maybe your system has problem with managing memory.

Comment: Why do they created .destroy() if it is not for this purpose ? del already delete the reference so it should be enough for the garbage collector. And we can't manage RAM with dynamic widget creation/destruction in tkinter if there is no way to free space ?
(I tried it on Windows 10)

Comment: `destroy()` in `tkinter` also removes item from screen. If you create window then you can close it with `window.destroy()`. And all code work correctly on Linux - it doesn't change size of used memory - so it is problem with Windows system. Or it is problem with `tkinter` on Windows. `tkinter` uses language `tcl/tk` and it can be also problem with `tcl/tk` on WIndows.

Comment: so it can be bug in `tkinter`, `tcl/tk` or special strategy in Window RAM manager and keep memory for longer time.